# Designing for s3 and nexus 4

Tags: android, screen-resolution

S3 is having resolution 720x1280. I have design for XHDPI (720x1280) and it looks fine in s3 also. but it cuts in nexus 4 (768x1280). same height with respect to s3. but still it goes in scroll.

It might be that nexus 4 is having bottom navigation bar. but what should be the solid solution to make compatible for both the resolution.

should I make the screen height by excluding the bottom navigation height?

Comment: provide your layout? You are probably looking for `layout-weight`

Answer (score 0):

The solid solution to make your app compatible for both (or any) resolution is to not make fixed size UI elements. Your controls should have size of wrap_content or match_parent. The content(i.e. bitmap) should be small enough to fit on the smallest supported screen. You should also provide separate layouts/resources for [different screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).